Computing $H^\ast$ from $E_2^{p,q}$ via Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence
Suppose that we are in the case where conditions for applying Lyndon–Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence hold. I've seen the next formula used more than once:
$$
H^i\left(G, \mathbb{Z}\right)=\bigoplus_{p+q=i}E^{pq}_2 
$$
I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that this holds when the differentials are trivial. So these are my questions:

Are there concrete conditions under which we can apply the formula above?
Can we apply the formula in any case where $E_2$ is concentrated in the first $n$ rows or columns, or do we need some condition over the differentials?
Is there a natural way to compute the differentials when $E_2$ is concentrated in the first $n$ rows or columns?

